# Cannot access Controller in init function of View in 1.0.0rc

Tags: ember.js

I have a view which is setup by a route plus an associated controller.
I can trace that the controller is created but in the `init()` function of the
view, when I do this:

```
init: function() {                  
  this._super();                     
  console.log(this.get('controller'));
}
```

The controller is `null`.
If I check in `didInsertElement()`, the controller is set.
I think it would be useful to have the controller in the `init()` function already.
Why is this not the case?

Comment: yes..you can't get in init() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the case, because **init() gets called when the View gets created (= the Ember Object)**. Somewhere Ember does something similar to the following. Then your init gets called.

```
var view = Ember.View.create({});
```

**At this point the controller is not assigned.** The controller is assigned at a later point. Most of the times, this is down by your route. Have a look at this code from the render code for Routes:

```
function setupView(view, container, options) {
  var defaultView = options.into ? 'view:default' : 'view:toplevel';

  view = view || container.lookup(defaultView); // the view gets created here and init gets called

  if (!get(view, 'templateName')) {
    set(view, 'template', options.template);

    set(view, '_debugTemplateName', options.name);
  }

  set(view, 'renderedName', options.name);
  set(view, 'controller', options.controller); // controller gets assigned to view

  return view;
}
```

As you can see, at first the view is instantiated and **afterwards the controller is assigned** to it.

**Why does Ember do it that way? Isn't it wrong?**
Your current understanding is, that there is always a controller connected with your view. But this is not always the case. Think of the {{view}} helper for example. Usually you set it up with a contextBinding. So the 'controller' property is not always set!

**What should you do in your case?**
You did not outline your requirements in detail, but you should be fine using the [willInsertElement](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_willInsertElement)() hook. This is before the element is in the DOM. That should be early enough to access it, right?

Comment: my actual issue is quite tough I posted it here now:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275955/realize-a-dynamic-master-detail-scenario-in-view-in-ember-1-0-0rc