# How to get any controller instance from init() method of a view?

Tags: ember.js

I am migrating my project from older version of EmberJS. In some places i used to get controller instance which is not related to the view, by using following in any view's init() method:

```
var controller = App.get('router').get('firstController');
```

But now this throws following error.

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
```

This may be because it is not able to get the Router object. Now how to get controller instance which is not related to the view? or how to get the Router Object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'needs' feature allows a controller to access to other controllers, which allows a controller's view to access other controllers. (a good explanation of needs in Ember: http://darthdeus.github.com/blog/2013/01/27/controllers-needs-explained/)

As explained in [Cannot access Controller in init function of View in 1.0.0rc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272318/cannot-access-controller-in-init-function-of-view-in-1-0-0rc), the `controller` property of a view is not yet set when `init()` is called, so you will need to access `controller` at a later time in the view's life cycle.  This could be the `willInsertElement()` or `didInsertElement()` hooks, for example.

Here is an example demonstrating using needs access another controller from a view:

http://jsbin.com/ixupad/186/edit

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  doSomething: function(message) {
    console.log(message);
  }
});

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'index',
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    // doesn't work, controller is not set for this view yet see:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272318/cannot-access-controller-in-init-function-of-view-in-1-0-0rc
    //this.get('controller.controllers.application').doSomething("from view init");
  },
  willInsertElement: function() {
    this.get('controller.controllers.application').doSomething("from view willInsertElement");
  },
  clickMe: function() {
    this.get('controller.controllers.application').doSomething("from clickMe"); 
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['application']
});
```

Comment: Thanks..it works...but i wonder whatz the motto in removing of getting router object and allowing this...the way i see it, if i have all the controllers in `needs` it will be working same..i may be wrong..previously it was just referencing..now an extra array...

Comment: @CodeJack here is a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166995/access-instance-of-new-ember-router

Comment: Thanks...now i feel like i have to refactor code as well...not just upgrade :)